# Symfony - Add a callback if entity not found

Tags: api, symfony, events, doctrine

I'm struggling with something for several days. I'm using API which stores data about food products.
What I would like to do is :

1. A user is looking for a product (using the bar code )
2. We search the product in the database
3. If nothing is found, then we reach the API to retrieve the information and we save them in the database
4. And then we process as usual with the loaded entity

Is there a way (event or other) to add a behavior in case of the entity does not exists in the DB ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the api throws a not found exception you could use try and catch method. can you show a piece of the api controller that tries to find a product?

Comment: It's not the API who must throw a not found exception. It's when the product cannot be found locally (in our database) that we're using an external API to fetch the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested code to illustrated the flow.

in your repository:

```
public function findByEAN(string $ean): Product
{
    $product = $this->findOnyBy(['ean' => $ean]);
    if ($product === null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(sprintf('No Product with EAN %s', $ean);
    }

    return $product;
}
```

in your controller action:

```
try {
    $product = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Product::class)->findByEan($request->get('ean'));
} catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
    $product = '' ; // fetch product via api and store in DB
}

return $product;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought about this solution but actually, it's not really suitable because you will have to add this behavior in every repository methods. Thus I was trying to find a better and more generic way to do so.

Comment: it was a simplified example - i for one hav an Abstract Base Repository with a couple of often used methods. so the basic findBy* and find* methods are rewritten to all throw an exception instead of just returning null. other methods return a object in all cases - if not found just creating a new one.

Comment: Yes but still. The developer will always have to think about it. The best way will be to have like anotation to specify a method to use if the data is null. In that way we can separate the "doctrine repo methods" and the "api repo methods".

Comment: imho best practice would be to use a `ProductManager` Class which consumes the entity manager and the api service. every find method goes over the manager - if no product is found it calls the api. so you have a central point for all your developers.

Comment: I like that way ! Thank you very much :)